# Android GridView Adapter customization

Tags: android, gridview, simplecursoradapter

I have a GridView and a SimpleCursorAdapter for this. The code looks like this

```
GridView myGridView = (GridView) this.freePassDialog.findViewById(R.id.gridview_buttons);
    String[] column = { "name", "type" };
    int[] viewIds = new int[] { R.id.name_button, R.id.type_button };

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.parent, R.layout.row_free_pass_buttons, cursor, column, viewIds) {

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * @see android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter#bindView(android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor)
         */
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            String freePassName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            String freePassType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
            Button freePassBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pass_name_button);
            if (PaymentMethodType.SMARTCARD_PASS == PaymentMethodType.valueOf(freePassType)) {
                freePassBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                freePassBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        }
    };
    myGridView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

The cursor has 4 values but for me if i put some loggers into BindView method only the first values comes several times
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with the code you posted...  although every example I can find of this sort of thing show overriding both `newView` as well as `bindView`.  Maybe you should implement a `newView` override?

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work ... i use the same code in other part of my app and works fine. In this place just don't see the entire content of cursor.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand... you are only getting one item in the gridview, or you are getting four copies of one item in the gridview?

Comment: I get only the first value from cursor but in many copies ... more than 4.